# How to create a JTable cell with scrollable content

Tags: java, swing, jtable, scroll, tablecellrenderer

I'd like to use a JTable to display some data. Sometimes the data can be little larger, so it is neccessary to be able to scroll inside the cells of the JTable.

I try to accomplish this with the code below. The table that is created looks fine, unfortunatly it doesn't work. The scrollbar doens't even seem to respond to mouse clicks.

How can I do this without the scrollbars "freezing" ?

thanks,

Thorsten

```
package main;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class ScrollableCellTableTest extends JPanel {

    JTable table;
    String val = "This is my totally cool test data. ";


    public ScrollableCellTableTest() {

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        for (int t=0; t<10; t++)
            val+=val;

        table = new JTable(new String[][]{{val}}, new String[]{"colname"}) {
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                return false;
            }
        };

        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0)
                .setCellRenderer(new ScrollableCellRenderer());

        add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        ScrollableCellTableTest scrollableCellTable = new ScrollableCellTableTest();
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollableCellTable, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocation(500, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

The cell renderer class:

```
package main;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

/**
 * Scrollable Cell Renderer.
 */
public class ScrollableCellRenderer extends JPanel implements
        TableCellRenderer {
    private List rowColHeight = new ArrayList();
    JScrollPane jScrollPane;
    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();

    public ScrollableCellRenderer() {
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(this);
    }

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

        textArea.setText(value.toString());

        adjustRowHeight(table, row, column);

        return new JScrollPane(this);
    }

    /**
     * Calculate the new preferred height for a given row, and sets the height
     * on the table.
     */
    private void adjustRowHeight(JTable table, int row, int column) {

        int cWidth = table.getTableHeader().getColumnModel().getColumn(column)
                .getWidth();
        setSize(new Dimension(cWidth, 1000));
        int prefH = getPreferredSize().height;

        // Limit the height, so scrollbars become neccessary
        prefH = Math.min(prefH, 100);


        while (rowColHeight.size() <= row) {
            rowColHeight.add(new ArrayList(column));
        }
        List colHeights = (List) rowColHeight.get(row);
        while (colHeights.size() <= column) {
            colHeights.add(new Integer(0));
        }
        colHeights.set(column, new Integer(prefH));
        int maxH = prefH;
        for (int t = 0; t < colHeights.size(); t++) {
            int colHeight = ((Integer) colHeights.get(t)).intValue();
            if (colHeight > maxH)
                maxH = colHeight;
        }
        if (table.getRowHeight(row) != maxH) {
            table.setRowHeight(row, maxH);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Renderer is used for drawing only. Read about TableCellEditor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach will never work because the renderer is only used to render the cell content. No interaction with renderer is possible. You can provide interaction with the cell content only by using editor. Unfortunately you can only have one editor at the same time. The only way to provide scrolling in actual cell is to install mouse listener which makes the currently pointed cell editable (probably with a little delay). In your listener you must monitor following events: moving (make cell at point editable), entering (same as for moving) and exiting (remove current editor if any exists). Probably this approach will also work without listener: the interface CellEditor defines the method `isCellEditable(EventObject anEvent)`. Here you should try to check whether the event is a mouse event and its ID is entering, moving or exiting. And don't forget to define the appropriate cells as editable in your table model!

Answer (score 0):

> Sometimes the data can be little larger

If it is only a "little" larger then the easiest solution is to use a tooltip. There are two ways to do this:

1. Create a custom renderer and invoke the `setToolTipText(...)` method in the renderer
2. Override the `getToolTipText(...)` method of JTable to return the tooltip.